# Swift Document

Tags: swift

Swiftのドキュメントにはどこに何が書かれていますか？ メソッドはあっても関数がないようにおもうんですが

Answer (score 2):

関数のドキュメントなら
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html

> Swiftのドキュメントにはどこに何が書かれていますか？ メソッドはあっても関数がないようにおもうんですが

ほぼすべてのプログラム言語で「メソッド」と「関数」は同じものです。（メンバ関数と非メンバ関数の違いだったりする場合がありますが本質的に差はない）なのでこの質問文では何を訊いているのか回答側にとっては意味不明です。こういう技術者の集まる場では、自分が答えてほしい回答が得られるような質問文を書く技術が必要です、要訓練。